# Who plays with these dice?

Tags: geometry, game

As I was visiting a gadget shop I noticed these dice that had this images from top, front, and side - presented in the picture. Than I noticed another feature and knew it. Who plays with these dice? The intended players use the dice as regular dice.
[image]

Comment: I'd say someone who is really bad at cheating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer:

> The dice are transparent. I'm not sure *why* someone would specifically need transparent dice, but with a standard layout, that's what a transparent die would look like. The front and back are 6 and 1, the sides are 5 and 2, and the top and bottom are 3 and 4.

It could be

> a nested die?
>  [image]
>  I know several tabletop roleplayers use these, and sometimes they're used for other games where you have to roll two dice at once.

Comment: Nice observation. There is an additional feature that allows a certain group of individuals to play with these dice effectively - any suggestions?

Comment: @Moti: Could it be this?

Comment: Challenge: Find an actual picture of an actual transparent die that actually looks at all like the pictures in the question :-).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: Well, if you look at it directly from the top/sides/back, it would.

Comment: I really don't think it actually would. You'd need to be looking from far enough away that parallax didn't screw it up, and from exactly the right angle to make the dots overlap as required. I guess it would be *possible* to make them look that way, but it would be super-unnatural and I don't think transparent dice would ever actually look to a casual passer-by the way they're shown here.

Comment: @Deusovi No. Just transparent is good enough. There is an additional feature which will allow a certain group of people to play effectively with the dice. A hint, from the people that can not play effectively with the dice you may deduce who could if you add some feature...

Comment: @Moti: Could it be bumps for the blind? I don't see how that would be related to the transparency...

Comment: You got it. The relation to transparency is: that it makes it first not convenient for people who see and does not bother blind people. You got the answer right.

Comment: @Moti: I've played with transparent dice before. They work fine.

Comment: Well... for blind people they do not introduce any difference in experience (use normally...?)

Comment: @Moti: They don't really for sighted people either. It's really easy to distinguish the locations of the bumps.

Comment: I too am not seeing (ha!) the connection between transparent dice and blind people. I would guess that if anything transparent dice are used more commonly by sighted people than by blind people (I mean Pr(transparent|sighted) > Pr(transparent|blind), not the boring Pr(transparent&sighted) > Pr(transparent&blind), of course).

Answer (score 2):

Well,

> one of the dice in a set of "[Efron dice](https://plus.maths.org/content/let-em-roll)" would have three faces with 5,5,7 spots on them.

I don't see why the question would have the "geometry" tag if that were what Moti has in mind, but assuming this isn't the intended answer perhaps Moti would like to narrow the question somehow so as to exclude it?

[Since I posted this, the question has been edited to include the words "The intended players use the dice as regular dice"; if that rules out this answer then I don't really see how...]

Answer (score 0):

The people who use these dice are:

> Scam Artists

These are called called:

> ["Non-Transitive Dice"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontransitive_dice).  A dice of one layout will have a winning probability over another, and that one will lose to the third, sort of like "Rock, Paper, Scissors".
>  Relevant Scam School video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQ0sdD61UGs

Comment: I think this answer (1) conflicts with the statement that the dice are used as regular dice -- the way you scam someone with nontransitive dice is something you wouldn't ever do with ordinary dice -- and (2) is essentially a duplicate of mine.